# Windows EC2 User Data Not Executing

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, user-data

The problem:

We need to execute a Powershell script using Userdata on a Windows AWS EC2 instance so that we can join and unjoin our domain's activity directory. The EC2 Userdata log shows the instance being stuck at:

```
Ec2HandleUserData :  is currently executing. To end it kill the process with id:
```

[We have tried adding lines of code documented here but no luck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html). Can anyone see what is being done wrong? Note we have commented out logging because we don't currently have CloudWatch setup. Script we are using is below and thank you for your help!

```
<powershell>
$file = $env:SystemRoot + "\Temp\" + (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm")
New-Item $file -ItemType file
# Script parameters
[string]$SecretAD = "prod/AD"
#class Logger {
#   #----------------------------------------------
#   [string] hidden  $cwlGroup
#   [string] hidden  $cwlStream
#   [string] hidden  $sequenceToken
#   #----------------------------------------------
#   # Log Initialization
#   #----------------------------------------------
#   Logger([string] $Action) {
#       $this.cwlGroup = "/ps/boot/configuration/"
#       $this.cwlStream = "{0}/{1}/{2}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $Action,
#       (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
#       $this.sequenceToken = ""
#       #------------------------------------------
#       if ( !(Get-CWLLogGroup -LogGroupNamePrefix $this.cwlGroup) ) {
#           New-CWLLogGroup -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup
#           Write-CWLRetentionPolicy -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -RetentionInDays 3
#       }
#       if ( !(Get-CWLLogStream -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -LogStreamNamePrefix $this.cwlStream) ) {
#           New-CWLLogStream -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream
#       }
#   }
#   #----------------------------------------
#   [void] WriteLine([string] $msg) {
#       #$logEntry = New-Object -TypeName "Amazon.CloudWatchLogs.Model.InputLogEvent"
#       #-----------------------------------------------------------
#       #$logEntry.Message = $msg
#       #$logEntry.Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
#       if ("" -eq $this.sequenceToken) {
#           # First write into empty log...
#           $this.sequenceToken = Write-CWLLogEvent -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup `
#               -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream `
#               -LogEvent #$logEntry
#       }
#       else {
#           # Subsequent write into the log...
#           $this.sequenceToken = Write-CWLLogEvent -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup `
#               -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream `
#               -SequenceToken $this.sequenceToken `
#               -LogEvent #$logEntry
#       }
#   }
#}
#[Logger]#$log = [Logger]::new("UserData")
#$log.WriteLine("------------------------------")
#$log.WriteLine("Log Started - V4.0")
$RunUser = 'TrustedInstaller'

Write-Output "I set the run user"

#$log.WriteLine("PowerShell session user: $RunUser")
class SDManager {
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    #[Logger] hidden $SDLog
    [string] hidden $GPScrShd_0_0 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0"
    [string] hidden $GPMScrShd_0_0 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0"
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    SDManager([string]$RegFilePath, [string]$SecretName) {
        #$this.SDLog = #$log
        #----------------------------------------------------------------
        [string] $SecretLine = '[string]$SecretAD    = "' + $SecretName + '"'
        #--------------- Local Variables -------------
        [string] $GPRootPath = "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy"
        [string] $GPMcnPath = "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine"
        [string] $GPScrPath = "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts"
        [string] $GPSShdPath = "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown"
        [string] $ScriptFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($GPSShdPath, "Shutdown-UnJoin.ps1")
        #region Shutdown script (scheduled through Local Policy)
        $ScriptBody =
        @(
            'param([string]$cntrl = "NotSet")',
            $SecretLine,
            '[string]$MachineName = $env:COMPUTERNAME',
            '#class Logger {    ',
            '#    #----------------------------------------------    ',
            '#    [string] hidden  $cwlGroup    ',
            '#    [string] hidden  $cwlStream    ',
            '#    [string] hidden  $sequenceToken    ',
            '#    #----------------------------------------------    ',
            '#    # Log Initialization    ',
            '#    #----------------------------------------------    ',
            '#    Logger([string] $Action) {    ',
            '#        $this.cwlGroup = "/ps/boot/configuration/"    ',
            '#        $this.cwlStream = "{0}/{1}/{2}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $Action,    ',
            '#                                           (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")    ',
            '#        $this.sequenceToken = ""    ',
            '#        #------------------------------------------    ',
            '#        if ( !(Get-CWLLogGroup -LogGroupNamePrefix $this.cwlGroup) ) {    ',
            '#            New-CWLLogGroup -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup    ',
            '#            Write-CWLRetentionPolicy -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -RetentionInDays 3    ',
            '#        }    ',
            '#        if ( !(Get-CWLLogStream -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -LogStreamNamePrefix $this.cwlStream) ) {    ',
            '#            New-CWLLogStream -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream    ',
            '#        }    ',
            '#    }    ',
            '#    #----------------------------------------    ',
            '#    [void] WriteLine([string] $msg) {    ',
            '#        #$logEntry = New-Object -TypeName "Amazon.CloudWatchLogs.Model.InputLogEvent"    ',
            '#        #-----------------------------------------------------------    ',
            '#        #$logEntry.Message = $msg    ',
            '#        #$logEntry.Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()    ',
            '#        if ("" -eq $this.sequenceToken) {    ',
            '#            # First write into empty log...    ',
            '#            $this.sequenceToken = Write-CWLLogEvent -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup `',
            '#                -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream `',
            '#                -LogEvent #$logEntry    ',
            '#        }    ',
            '#        else {    ',
            '#            # Subsequent write into the log...    ',
            '#            $this.sequenceToken = Write-CWLLogEvent -LogGroupName $this.cwlGroup `',
            '#                -LogStreamName $this.cwlStream `',
            '#                -SequenceToken $this.sequenceToken `',
            '#                -LogEvent #$logEntry    ',
            '#        }    ',
            '#    }    ',
            '#}    ',
            '#[Logger]#$log = [Logger]::new("UnJoin")',
            '#$log.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------")',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Log Started")',
            'if ($cntrl -ne "run") ',
            '    { ',
            '    #$log.WriteLine("Script param <" + $cntrl + "> not set to <run> - script terminated") ',
            '    return',
            '    }',
            '$compSys = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem',
            'if ( -Not ($compSys.PartOfDomain))',
            '    {',
            '    #$log.WriteLine("Not member of a domain - terminating script")',
            '    return',
            '    }',
            '$RSAT = (Get-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell)',
            'if ( $RSAT -eq $null -or (-Not $RSAT.Installed) )',
            '    {',
            '    #$log.WriteLine("<RSAT-AD-PowerShell> feature not found - terminating script")',
            '    return',
            '    }',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Removing machine <" +$MachineName + "> from Domain <" + $compSys.Domain + ">")',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Reading Secret <" + $SecretAD + ">")',
            #'Import-Module AWSPowerShell',
            #'try { $SecretObj = (Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId $SecretAD) }',
            #'catch ',
            #'    { ',
            #'    #$log.WriteLine("Could not load secret <" + $SecretAD + "> - terminating execution")',
            #'    return ',
            #'    }',
            #'[PSCustomObject]$Secret = ($SecretObj.SecretString  | ConvertFrom-Json)',
            '$password   = "<password>"',
            '$username   = "<username>"',
            '$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)',
            'import-module ActiveDirectory',
            '$DCHostName = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover).HostName',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Using Account <" + $username + ">")',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Using Domain Controller <" + $DCHostName + ">")',
            'Remove-Computer -WorkgroupName "WORKGROUP" -UnjoinDomainCredential $credential -Force -Confirm:$false ',
            'Remove-ADComputer -Identity $MachineName -Credential $credential -Server "$DCHostName" -Confirm:$false ',
            '#$log.WriteLine("Machine <" +$MachineName + "> removed from Domain <" + $compSys.Domain + ">")'
        )
        #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Constracting artifacts required for domain UnJoin")
        #----------------------------------------------------------------
    Write-Output "I created SDManager class"

        try {
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $GPRootPath -pathType container))
            { New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $GPRootPath }
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $GPMcnPath -pathType container))
            { New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $GPMcnPath }
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $GPScrPath -pathType container))
            { New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $GPScrPath }
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $GPSShdPath -pathType container))
            { New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $GPSShdPath }
        }
        catch {
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Failure creating UnJoin script directory!" )
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine($_)
            Write-Output  "hello"
        }
        #----------------------------------------
        try {
            Set-Content $ScriptFile -Value $ScriptBody
        }
        catch {
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Failure saving UnJoin script!" )
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine($_)
            Write-Output  "hello"
        }
        #----------------------------------------
        
# UPDATE WINDOWS REGISTRY AND CREATE A SHUTDOWN TASK        
        
        $RegistryScript =
        @(
            'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts]',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown]',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown\0]',
            '"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"',
            '"SOM-ID"="Local"',
            '"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"',
            '"DisplayName"="Local Group Policy"',
            '"GPOName"="Local Group Policy"',
            '"PSScriptOrder"=dword:00000001',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0]',
            '"Script"="Shutdown-UnJoin.ps1"',
            '"Parameters"=""',
            '"IsPowershell"=dword:00000001',
            '"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup]',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts]',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown]',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0]',
            '"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"',
            '"SOM-ID"="Local"',
            '"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"',
            '"DisplayName"="Local Group Policy"',
            '"GPOName"="Local Group Policy"',
            '"PSScriptOrder"=dword:00000001',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0]',
            '"Script"="Shutdown-UnJoin.ps1"',
            '"Parameters"=""',
            '"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00',
            '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup]'
        )
        Write-Output "I created the registry script."

        try {
            [string] $RegistryFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($RegFilePath, "OnShutdown.reg")
            Set-Content $RegistryFile -Value $RegistryScript
            &regedit.exe /S "$RegistryFile"
        }
        catch {
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Failure creating policy entry in Registry!" )
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine($_)
            Write-Output "hello"
        }
    }

#DISABLE UNJOIN AND ENABLE JOIN FOR THE FIRST RUN
    
    #----------------------------------------
    [void] DisableUnJoin() {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $this.GPScrShd_0_0  -Name "Parameters" -Value "ignore"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $this.GPMScrShd_0_0 -Name "Parameters" -Value "ignore"
            &gpupdate /Target:computer /Wait:0
        }
        catch {
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Failure in <DisableUnjoin> function!" )
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine($_)
            Write-Output  "hello"
        }
    }
    #----------------------------------------
    [void] EnableUnJoin() {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $this.GPScrShd_0_0  -Name "Parameters" -Value "run"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $this.GPMScrShd_0_0 -Name "Parameters" -Value "run"
            &gpupdate /Target:computer /Wait:0
        }
        catch {
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine("Failure in <EnableUnjoin> function!" )
            #$this.SDLog.WriteLine($_)
            Write-Output "hello"
        }
    }
}
Write-Output "I created the the join and unjoin functions"
# GET SECRETS

#[SDManager]$sdm = [SDManager]::new(#$log, "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts", $SecretAD)
##$log.WriteLine("Loading Secret <" + $SecretAD + ">")
#Import-Module AWSPowerShell
#try { $SecretObj = (Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId $SecretAD) }
#catch {
#   #$log.WriteLine("Could not load secret <" + $SecretAD + "> - terminating execution")
#   return
#}
#[PSCustomObject]$Secret = ($SecretObj.SecretString  | ConvertFrom-Json)
##$log.WriteLine("Domain (from Secret): <" + $domain + ">")



# Verify domain membership

#IF ALREADY MEMBER OF DOMAIN 

$compSys = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ( ($compSys.PartOfDomain) -and ($compSys.Domain -eq $domain)) {
    #$log.WriteLine("Already member of: <" + $compSys.Domain + "> - Verifying RSAT Status")
    
    #CHECK IF RSTAT IS INSTALLED
    
    $RSAT = (Get-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell)
    if ($null -eq $RSAT) {
        #$log.WriteLine("<RSAT-AD-PowerShell> feature not found - terminating script")
        return
    }
    
    #ENABLE ON SHUT DOWN & INSTALL RSTAT
    
    #$log.WriteLine("Enable OnShutdown task to un-join Domain")
    $sdm.EnableUnJoin()
    if ( (-Not $RSAT.Installed) -and ($RSAT.InstallState -eq "Available") ) {
        #$log.WriteLine("Installing <RSAT-AD-PowerShell> feature")
        Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
    }
    #$log.WriteLine("Terminating script - ")
    return
}

# IF NOT MEMBER OF DOMAIN THEN JOIN AND RESTART

# Performing Domain Join
#$log.WriteLine("Domain Join required")
#$log.WriteLine("Disable OnShutdown task to avoid reboot loop")
$sdm.DisableUnJoin()
$password = "<password>"
$username = "<username>"
$domain = "<domain>"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
#$log.WriteLine("Attempting to join domain <" + $domain + ">")
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -Restart -Force
#$log.WriteLine("Requesting restart...")

Write-Output "I joined or unjoined the domain friends."
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you find an answer?  I believe your inline script is too long to be executed in userdata.  You're likely running into the issue here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html

When I run into this, I find it best to upload the script to S3, allow the EC2 instance RO access to the S3 bucket via the EC2 instance profile, then pull from the bucket and run the script in the userdata.

HTH!